# Elastic search date range with match not working

Tags: elasticsearch, search, elasticsearch-5

I am trying to get the records which match a specific field with between 2 dates as below

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
         "must": [
            {
              "range": {
                "createdtime": {
                  "gte": "now-1y",
                  "lte": "now",
                  "boost" : 2.0
                }
              }
            },
            {
               "match": {
                  "id": 350403
               }
            }
         ]
    }
  }
    "size" : 10000,
    "from": 0,
    "sort": { "createdtime" : {"order" : "desc"} }
```

but it throws the exception, can anyone help to fix it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should properly format and indent your query, it's easier to spot errors. The correct query can be found below:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "range": {
            "createdtime": {
              "gte": "now-1y",
              "lte": "now",
              "boost": 2
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "match": {
            "id": 350403
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "size": 10000,
  "from": 0,
  "sort": {
    "createdtime": {
      "order": "desc"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes, the intent is the problem, now it seems working.

Comment: The boost is applied only for term queries (prefix, range and fuzzy queries can not be boosted).